# Storing and working with huge dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to load a dictionary with around 11,000 pairs into a Swift program (about .7MB). The values of the dictionary are arrays, and I need to be able to loop through the dictionary's arrays and compare those values with values in another array. There is an average of 10 items in the subarrays, although some have two or three, and some have hundreds.

The program crashes, and I am looking for a way to fix it while keeping the functionality from my Python-based prototype. I was thinking of using a bunch of property lists, and loading them into memory one by one, but this seems inefficient. What can I do to redesign this?

Some of the code which is being problematic:`var dictOfHashesAndMaterials:[String:[Int]]: = ["10928123sdfb234w3fw3": [123,435,1,573,456,3234,653,57856,434,345],"13435fw323df0239dfsdf":[435,756,978,231,5668,485,9678,1233,87,989]] // and 11,000 additional entries which look similar to this.`

And here's where I use it:`    // function to populate the list of ingredients.
    func populateListOfRecipes(){
        var storedIngredients = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ingredients") as! [Int]

```
    for(key, value) in dictOfHashesAndMaterials{
        let listSet = Set(storedMaterials)
        let findListSet = Set(value)
        if findListSet.isSubset(of: listSet){
            print("found a match!")
            arrayOfAvailableProjects.append(key)
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}`
```

A tableView is then populated by cells which link to the specifics of a given project. The details are filled in when the hashes are sent to the server, and the corresponding instructions are returned in full to the app.

Comment: Can you describe the crash any better?

Comment: When initializing the literal, both Xcode and the simulator freeze, and the report indicates that the process was unresponsive for a number of minutes. When I examine the crash report, I see that the dictionary object which was in the process of being created is taking up around 350mb of space on memory. My assumption is that the object is so large, and that the calls to the object are so frequent that the machine cannot handle it. Just to clarify, copy/pasting the dictionary into a text file is .7 megs. The actual object is probably much bigger.

Comment: You need to show some code, but note that Swift dictionaries are copy-on-modify structures, so each time you modify a dictionary a new copy is made. If you do this in a loop then arc will not have an opportunity to clean up the obsolete copies. You may be better using NSMutableDictionary or modifying your "load" code. Can you show some code?

Comment: I'll add some code in the original post. It won't let me do it nicely in the comments.

Comment: A workaround which I was considering, but have some major concerns with in terms of speed is building a sqlite database, key = hash, value = arrayOfMaterials, and then polling each entry in the db individually when the app loads before displaying the available projects to the user.

Comment: Also, important to note that I'm never actually modifying the dictionary, just accessing its contents. Though, I suppose that the initialization of the dict could be considered a modification.

Comment: Try putting the contents of your for loop in an `autoreleasepool` block, but it sounds like it isn't even getting that far; it is initialising the literal that is the issue.  You can also use Instruments to analyse memory use,  but you may find it is better to load data from an external source such as a plist than use a large literal. Also if the dictionary is never mutated, use `let` rather than `var`

Answer (score 2):

Is it crashing in the simulator? I've worked with 30 GB files using the simulator without a crash.  On the device is a different story...

Anyway, try this:

```
for(key, value) in dictOfHashesAndMaterials{
     autoreleasepool {
        let listSet = Set(storedMaterials)
        let findListSet = Set(value)
        if findListSet.isSubset(of: listSet){
            print("found a match!")
            arrayOfAvailableProjects.append(key)
        }
    }
}

tableView.reloadData()
```

}

By draining the auto release pool every iteration you will prevent running out of available memory.

Comment: So did it make a difference, or is the problem occurring before you get to this loop, as Paulw11 suggests?